# Get colour highlighted cells from excel

Tags: excel, vba

I got an excel sheet with randomly placed yellow highlighted cells. In these cells, there are keywords that I need to use. It is possible to copy all these cells to a row ? I found that it is possible to search for cells with find all but the output cannot be copied.

Comment: I see you have canceled my answer. Is something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do it via a `Find` command, then you can record that into a macro and, if needed, modify it to your wishes, e.g.:

[image]

Recording this command results in following VBA macro:

```
With Application.FindFormat.Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=True).Activate
```